# У бегемота есть хвост. Хвост — чей?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, прилагательные

Собственно, интересует, как образовать ***прилагательное*** от слова **бегемот**.
Хвост — чей? Если бы был гиппопотам, то, понятно, "гиппопотамий" — по аналогии с кошачий, собачий и лошадиный. А вот как быть с бегемотом? Бегемотий? Бегемотьячий?
Помогите, пожалуйста, образовать слово.

Answer (score 3):

**Бегемотовый** хвост. В биологической классификации есть даже такое семейство - *бегемотовые*.
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

В словаре дается форма: бегемотовый.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: бегемочий.

Comment: Точнее, бегемотий.  А если это имя кота Бегемота, то Бегемотов. А вообще я думаю, что хвост у бегемота бегемотский - я бы такой не хотела.

Comment: Бегемочий  лучше,  чем  бегемотий.